# Android "Touchdown" application breaking buttons in my app

Tags: android, webview

I have searched Google pretty hard and could not find an answer for this.  I have an Android application that uses a webview control to serve up HTML pages stored locally in the assets folder of my application.  The application works great.  But when a user installs Touchdown for Android, all of the links in my application are broken.  If you uninstall Touchdown, they all work again.  I've emailed NitroDesk, but no response after a couple days.

To simplify this, I did a very basic test.  I placed a link(`<a href="MyPage.html">test</a>`) on my home screen.  When Touchdown is **not** installed, it works totally fine.  When Touchdown is installed, I tap the link, the page flashes, but goes back to the home screen.  I uninstall Touchdown, and it woks again.

I'm assuming Touchdown does something to the webview control?  Maybe I'm missing something in the manifest to prevent other applications from changing the webview control I'm using in mine?

A full link does work, eg... I tested (`<a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>`) and that works with or without Touchdown installed.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does the locally stored page load or does the screen just flash? If it doesn't, I would look at the folder structure before and after the install of Touchdown.